# C# Linq merge a list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the code below, It is a list of Dictionaries merged to one Dictionary can this be written with linq?

```
    public static Dictionary<string, uint> mergeDictionaries(List<Dictionary<string, uint>> dictlist)
    {
        Dictionary<string, uint> mergedDict = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
        foreach (Dictionary<string, uint> dict in dictlist)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, uint> entry in dict)
            {
                if (mergedDict.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
                {
                    mergedDict[entry.Key] = mergedDict[entry.Key] + entry.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    mergedDict[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        return mergedDict;
    }
```

Comment: 99% of the time when people use `ContainsKey` they should have used `TryGetValue`. This is such a time.

Comment: The two dictionaries - are they using custom comparers (e.g. are they case insensitive)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dictlist
    .SelectMany(dict => dict)
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value))
```

Comment: error CS1929: 'IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, uint>>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<decimal>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<decimal>'

Comment: Oops; that should be `.Value`.  Fixed.